# SLURM: run jobs in parallel instead of as array?

Tags: arrays, slurm

I have a large file to analyze using "jellyfish query", which is not multithreaded. I have split the big file into 29 manageable fragments, to run as an array on SLURM. However, these are sitting in the workload queue for ages, whereas if I could request a whole node (32 cpus) they would get in a separate queue with quicker availability. Is there a way to tell SLURM to run the command on these fragments in parallel across all the cpus in a node, instead of as a serial array?

Comment: My earlier answer might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49299957/2646505

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for 29 tasks, 1 cpu per task (you will get from 29 cpus on a node to 1 cpu in 29 different nodes), and in the slurm script you should start your calculus with srun, telling srun to allocate one task/cpu per chunk.

```
.
.
.
#SBATCH --ntasks=29
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
.
.
.

for n in {1..29}
do
    srun -n 1 <your_script> $n &
done
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running a python script to multithread this for you, then submit a SLURM job to run the python script.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess

num_threads = 29

def sample_function(input_file):
    return subprocess.run(["cat", input_file], check=True).stdout

input_file_list = ['one','two','three']

pool = Pool(processes=num_threads)
[pool.apply_async(sample_function, args=(input_file,)) for input_file in input_file_list]

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This assumes you have files "one", "two", and "three". Obviously you need to replace:

1. the input file list
2. job you want to run with `subprocess`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions! I found a much less elegant but still functional way:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=32
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1

jellyfish query...fragment 1 &
jellyfish query...fragment 2 &
...
jellyfish query...fragment 29 
wait
```